# mongoose schema, is it better to have one or have several for different tasks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I'm been making a site that has comments section, messaging, profile and shopping for the user. I been wondering about when making a schema for those functions, is it better to have all in one schema like

```
userSchema {
    name: String,
    ....
    ....
}
```

or have them seperate like

```
userSchema {
}

commentSchema {

}

gallerySchema {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No one can give you clear answer for this, everyone has different views.

Basically, It depends on your project's scalability

As I see your requirement for this project

You can create a single schema and use it as embedded form, but it's not a very good idea if you are scaling the app.

> My recommendation is to create the separate schema for all the tasks which will be easy to debug,scaling the app and in readable form.

**Edit**

If you are creating separate schema and want to connect them then you can use `populate` on the basis of `ObjectId`

See the docs to [populate collections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

**Example**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

**Population**

```
Story
.findOne({ title: 'Once upon a timex.' })
.populate('_creator')
.exec(function (err, story) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log('The creator is %s', story._creator.name);
  // prints "The creator is Aaron"
});
```

Comment: if I were to do separate schema, how does the _id get passed between them such as the userSchema and the commentSchema for the user comments posts? Like how do you connect them together?

Comment: You can do populate to join each collection, see my updated example do for more details see the mongoose docs for populating http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html